# Position divs from side-to-side to top-to-bottom

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a third div. Div A is on the left, occupying 30% of the space. Div B is on the right, occupying 70% of the space.

When the width of the screen becomes too small to fit them side by side, I would like to position div B on top and div A on the bottom.[image]

I have considered replicating div A before and after B. For normal width I would show A1 and hide A2. For smaller width I would show A2 and hide A1.

However this seems like a dirty trick. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `order` property of flexbox module, you can check this codepen [example](https://codepen.io/tecayehuatl/pen/yLNymNE), you only need to add some breakpoints when you need to change the order, the order is applied to each child element of flexbox container

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is a good choice for this case.
By defining a media query for widths less than 575px and using `flex-direction:column` and set `order` for both ***divs*** you can arrange them as desired.
Below is an example I hope will help you:

```css
        .Main{
            display: flex;
            height: 150px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 2rem;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 150px;
        }
        .A{
            flex-basis: 30%;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .B{
            flex-basis: 70%;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
            .Main{
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            .B{
                order: 0;
            }
            .A{
                order: 1;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="Main">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
</div>
```